# I need to sort a map which have around 100 key value pairs as "H":"Hector", "A":"Alpha" and so on, I need to sort first 10 in a specific order

Tags: sorting, filter, collections, java-8, java-stream

```
Map<String, String> records = new HashMap<>();
        HOSTING.put("H", "Hector");
        HOSTING.put("B", "Bravo");
        HOSTING.put("W", "Whiskey");
        HOSTING.put("P", "Papa");


Map<String, String> finalMap = records .entrySet().stream().filter(x-> {
            if(x.getKey().equals("W") || x.getKey().equals("B")){
                return true;
            }
                return false;
        }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
System.out.println("finalMap"+finalMap);
```

I need "W" and "B" the first 2 entries and then rest all, I tried filter but that leaves me with only values as W and B, instead I am trying to have all the entries but first 2 entries to be of my choice.

Kindly help.

Comment: I suppose, `records` and `HOSTING` are meant to be the same map?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a sorted result, you have to use `sorted`, not `filter`. But then, you also need to collect into a map that will retain the order:

```java
Map<String, String> records = new HashMap<>();
records.put("H", "Hector");
records.put("B", "Bravo");
records.put("W", "Whiskey");
records.put("P", "Papa");

Map<String, String> finalMap = records.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
        x -> !(x.getKey().equals("W") || x.getKey().equals("B"))))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        (a,b) -> { throw new AssertionError("keys should be unique already"); },
        LinkedHashMap::new));
System.out.println("finalMap"+finalMap);
```

Here, you can easily expand the set of elements to be placed at the beginning.

Note that we have to negate the condition, as the natural order of `Boolean` is `false`, `true`.

But since your question’s title says “first 10”, you probably want something more scalable:

```java
Set<String> toTheTop = Set.of("B", "W");
Map<String, String> finalMap = records.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> !(toTheTop.contains(x.getKey()))))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        (a,b) -> { throw new AssertionError("keys should be unique already"); },
        LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Here, you can easily expand the set of keys to be placed at the beginning.

As a side note, don’t write something like `if(condition) return true; [else] return false;`
You can simply write `return condition;` or in case of a lambda expression, just `parameter -> condition`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, worked like a charm.

Comment: Then your can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `TreeMap` to sort the keys. You can control the key ordering:

```
Comparator<String> c = (s1,s2) -> {
      int c1 = s1.charAt(0);
      int c2 = s2.charAt(0);
      // H will be the first of all
      if (c1=='H') return -1;
      if (c2=='H') return 1;
      // W the second
      if (c1=='W') return -1;
      if (c2=='W') return 1;
      // Others in alphabetic order.
      return c1-c2;
    };
    Map<String, String> records = new TreeMap<>(c);
    records.put("H", "Hector");
    records.put("B", "Bravo");
    records.put("W", "Whiskey");
    records.put("P", "Papa");    
    System.out.println("finalMap"+records);
```